# Using a variable in css to set the font-family causes scroll issues

Tags: html, css

Problem is that scrolling works only after second attempt. So when I try to scroll down, it doesn't work. When trying the second time, it works. Then, if I try to scroll up, it doesn't work. I try again, it works.

I have a link for a font and a variable for it:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

:root {
    --font-primary: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

And somewhere in the main css file:

```
body.redesign-2019 * {
    font-family: var(--font-primary);
}
```

If I disable the * {} rule, scroll works normally.

Any ideea of why that happens?

Comment: Could you try if the issue still occurs if you change to rule's selector to simply `body` or `body.redesign-2019` (in other words, remove `*`)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no that didn't work. Weird part is that removing it completely was working. Found out though that html,body was set to overflow-x: hidden. I think hat made the first attempt of scrolling look like it was a full page. Still weird, since it should have been overflow-y to take care of that. So set the overflow-x to unset, and all is working now